# The static tab does not get the user's context

Tags: javascript, html, json, vue.js, microsoft-teams

I work for some time on a Teams application that is composed of a bot. I need to include a tab to allow my app to display additional information to the user.
I followed the microsoft documentation carefully.

My problem today is that I do not get the user information in my static tab.

**manifest.json**

```
{
        "$schema": "https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/manifest/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
        "manifestVersion": "1.0",
        "version": "1.0.0",
        "id": "{APP_ID}",
        "packageName": "{PACKAGE_NAME}",
        "developer": {
                "name": "Maxence de OpenAgora",
                "websiteUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com",
                "privacyUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/privacy",
                "termsOfUseUrl": "https://www.microsoft.com/termsofuse"
        },
        "staticTabs": [
                {
                        "entityId": "{IDENTITY_ID}",
                        "name": "{TAB_NAME}",
                        "contentUrl": "{CONTENT_URL}",
                        "websiteUrl": "{MY_WEBSITE_URL}",
                        "scopes": [
                                "team",
                                "personal"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "configurableTabs": [
                {
                        "configurationUrl": "{MY_URL}/configuration_tab.html",
                        "canUpdateConfiguration": true,
                        "scopes": [
                                "team"
                        ]
                }
        ],
        "permissions": [
                "identity",
                "messageTeamMembers"
        ],
        "validDomains": [
                "{MY_URL}"
        ]
}
```

All the URLs present in the file work and are accessible by microsoft.

**configuration.html**

```
<html>
<body>

<script src="https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    microsoftTeams.initialize();
    microsoftTeams.settings.setSettings({
        entityId: "{IDENTITY_ID}",
        contentUrl: "{CONTENT_URL}",
        suggestedDisplayName: "Max Agora",
        websiteUrl: "{MY_WEBSITE_URL}",
        removeUrl: "",
        scope: ['team', 'personal']
    });
    microsoftTeams.settings.setValidityState(true);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**index.html** (= {CONTENT_URL})

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.13/semantic.css">
    <title>VueJS Test</title>
</head>

<body>

    <div class="ui inverted fixed menu">
        <div class="header item">Tutoriel</div>
    </div>
    <div class="ui main container" id="app" style="padding-top: 50px">
        <div class="ui message">{{ message }}</div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://statics.teams.microsoft.com/sdk/v1.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js">
        microsoftTeams.initialize()
    </script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.3/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue-resource/1.3.4/vue-resource.js"></script>
    <script src="/public/js/app.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**/public/app.js** : I use this file to test the context and display it but callback never called

```
let vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        message: ""
    },
    mounted () {
        this.message = "Test" // it works
        microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => { this.message = "Toto" });//do nothings
        microsoftTeams.getSettings((settings) => { this.message = "Toto" });//do nothings too
    }

});
```

I followed the instructions from these links:

- [tabs-configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-configuration)
- [get context from tab](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/tabs/tabs-context)

I tried the two methods proposed in the documentation, the SDK js, and the query parameters (by modifying the **contentUrl** in **manifest.json**):

```
"contentUrl": "{CONTENT_URL}?name={upn}&tenant={tid}&group={groupId}"
```

Thank you for your time and help

Comment: you will not get the information related to groups in the static tab where as you can get the upn and tenant id while calling the getContext() method in the static tabs while the groupid and channelid are empty

Comment: Okay, but how can I get this information back? Are there any other types of tabs?
Otherwise I never get my event context (no tenantID and upn), the message never appears in my message field. @SrinivasNaidu-MSFT

Comment: There are only staticTabs and configurable tabs as of now. You can the context of by calling the microsoftTeams.getContext((context) => { console.log(context)  }); method. just log the context object and check it in the browsers developers tool window.